# PDO insert into with SELECT and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, pdo

I use the below query with succes, this query is only executed if a row in data_advertentie with the ID exists.

```
INSERT INTO data_contactgegevens (ID_advertentie, telefoonnummer, website)
SELECT ID_advertentie, :telefoonnummer, :website FROM data_advertenties
WHERE ID_advertentie = :ID_advertentie AND unieke_hash_plaatsen = :hash_plaatsen
```

Now i want to add a ON DUPLICATE KEY, so if the row exists in data_contactgegevens the row wil be updated.

Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `on duplicate key update` piece at the end of your `insert` statement.

**Example**

```sql
create table a(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  x varchar(10)
);

create table b(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  y varchar(10)
);

insert into a(x) values ('a'), ('b'), ('c');

insert into b(y) values ('e'), ('d');

insert into a
  select * from b
  on duplicate key update x = y;
```

Result:

```sql
select * from a;

| ID | X |
|----|---|
|  1 | e |
|  2 | d |
|  3 | c |
```

Here's the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc781f/1) for this example.

Comment: With an index UNIQUE on the ID_advertentie in table data_contactgegevens the PDO query now looks like:
    INSERT INTO data_contactgegevens (ID_advertentie, telefoonnummer, website)
                    SELECT ID_advertentie, :telefoonnummer, :website FROM data_advertenties
                    WHERE ID_advertentie = :ID_advertentie AND unieke_hash_plaatsen = :hash_plaatsen
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE telefoonnummer = :telefoonnummer, website = :website